# css affecting one div when img is hovered

Tags: css

i've searched around and seen some examples of how this is done, but i don't really get it and tried all methods but none worked, so i would like to ask if anyone can show me, for my code below, how can i affect the tournytitle when the img is hovered?

```
<div id="upevents" class="righty">
    <div>
        <div class="tournytitle">
        <div style="font-weight: bold;">Test 2 Hat</div>
        <div style="color: #888888; font-size: 10px;">17 . 12 . 2011</div>
        </div>
        <img src="/images/tourny/jomjom2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="tournytitle">
        <div style="font-weight: bold;">Test 1 Hat</div>
        <div style="color: #888888; font-size: 10px;">12 . 12 . 2011</div>
        </div>
        <img src="/images/tourny/bane5.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

how should i write my css code for this?

i tried something like

.upevents img:hover + #tournytitle { background-color: yellow; }

but doesn't seem to work.

help much apperciated

Comment: Why don't you try a Javascript based solution?

Comment: if it's possible, i don't want to.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, your `.tournytitle` class must be a child of the `img` your trying to roll over.  Your code `.upevents img:hover + #tournytitle { background-color: yellow; }` is certainly close, you just need to figure out how to comply to the above rule.  With this your saying that `.tournytitle` is an adjacent-child of `img`, which is not the case in your given code.  Also, your class and id symbols are incorrect, watch out for that.

I managed to get your code working by switching `.tournytitle` and `img` so that the class is now the adjacent-sibling - http://jsfiddle.net/gmwjw/1/ - I realize this may not be the design your looking for, but its a start.

This may be helpful to you - http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200007a.html

Comment: Thanks! seem really close! just need to figure out a way to switch or some tricks.

Answer (score 0):

The .tourneytitle must be a child of the img element for you to achieve this. This fiddle shows the way you can reveal your image by hovering over your `.tournytitle`: http://jsfiddle.net/fWxH3/203/

To get what you want, you would need to change your HTML so that somehow your `tournytitle` `div` is a child of your `img` tag. Maybe you can use `span`'s inside of your image tag instead of using `div`'s for everything.